# Why is part of my mesh rendering in black?

Tags: rendering

enter image description hereI am extremely new to blender and I made a small low poly island as a test. For some reason, the rocks and only the rocks showed up black in the rendering. I have tried a couple of things already, but none of them made any difference (Note that it is possible I did them wrong) :

- Added various light sources
- Toggled Local View
- Moved the object around the planes

The only other thing to note is that when i constructed it, it was half-way inside the x/y plane and that the rocks were all together and the whole land area (incuding grass and rocks) was one distorted Ico Sphere.

Thank you for any help and your time!
Best regards
[image]
This is the island in the editor

[image]
and here is the island once rendered

Comment: Please provide a screenshot or even better, provide the .blend-file itself.

Comment: @TobiasE Ideally, blend files should be supplemental to screenshots and text. The best case scenario for a question is that we don't have to download something to answer it.

Comment: I added screen shots, but I am not sure how to add a file, if it is necessary could you please tell me how?

Comment: Did you try rotating the extra lights added? It looks like they are all pointed directly down. Blender render will show black for 0 light.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no idea you had to rotate the lights!